# MongoDB: Add field from Aggregation Output to Query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I would like to perform an aggregation query, then a find query, and apply the output of the aggregation as a new field in the find results, ie:

A have dataset like this:

```
{id: 1, city: "Paris", comment: "...", status: "Active"},
{id: 2, city: "London", comment: "...", status: "Active"},
{id: 3, city: "Paris", comment: "...", status: "Active"},
{id: 4, city: "New York", comment: "...", status: "Active"},
{id: 5, city: "London", comment: "...", status: "Active"},
{id: 6, city: "London", comment: "...", status: "Active"},
{id: 7, city: "London", comment: "...", status: "Disabled"}
```

I want to get the counts for each active city:

```
collection.aggregate([
    {$match: {status: "Active"}},
    {$group: {_id: "$city", count: {$sum: 1}}}
])
```

But I would like to apply the count to each entry, matched according to city. It would return something like this:

```
{id: 1, city: "Paris", comment: "...", status: "Active", count: 2},
{id: 2, city: "London", comment: "...", status: "Active", count: 3},
{id: 3, city: "Paris", comment: "...", status: "Active", count: 2},
{id: 4, city: "New York", comment: "...", status: "Active", count: 1},
{id: 5, city: "London", comment: "...", status: "Active", count: 3},
{id: 6, city: "London", comment: "...", status: "Active", count: 3},
{id: 7, city: "London", comment: "...", status: "Disabled", count: 3}
```

Ideally I would like to do this in a single query so that it can be sorted and paginated according to count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$group` by `city` and push root object to a `root` field, `count` status that is `Active` only
- `$unwind` deconstruct `root` array
- `$mergeObjects` to merge `$root` object and `count` field
- `$replaceRoot` to replace merged object to root

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$city",
      root: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
      count: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [{ $eq: ["$status", "Active"] }, 1, 0]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$root" },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: { $mergeObjects: ["$root", { count: "$count" }] }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9RmzFfOtyUm)